# I replied to an emailed postdoc offer asking for a formal offer letter. Will it be interpreted as acceptance?

Tags: ethics, postdocs, job-search, email

I am a graduating PhD student. I received a postdoc offer informally saying that I have been accepted. In reply I told them that I am looking forward to a formal offer letter. Will it be interpreted as my acceptance by the PI? I am still waiting for some results, however I can't provide a timeline to this PI as those offers may take unexpected time. Please guide me what should be my course of action. I am worried that if the PI gets upset it may harm my reputation in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be foolish of them to make that interpretation, but who can say. A formal letter, spelling out all terms is needed before you can make a formal acceptance.

Relax. It is done. It is (or should be) a small matter. I doubt that there is anything you can do at the moment until the offer is formalized. But you may have to make a real decision before all potential offers appear.

I don't see what "long term" consequences there could be if you reject, even if they've made poor assumptions.

Comment: "I don't see what "long term" consequences there could be if you reject, even if they've made poor assumptions." -- I may want to collaborate with him or someone from his group in near future.

Answer (score 1):

If you tell someone you want a formal job offer, they will think you are planning to accept it.  But it will not hurt your reputation among reasonable people if you do not.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for an offer is not acceptance.  In contract law offer comes before acceptance, and a request for an offer is (at most) considered to be an ["invitation to treat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_to_treat).  Of course, if you ask for a formal offer and then do not accept it, they might be a bit annoyed (and confused).